# Why does the increment/decrement operators break the recursion functionality

Tags: c++

```
func(int n)
// the function should return the sum of the first n term of the 
// harmonic series (1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n )

double sumover(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        return (1. / n) + sumover(--n);  // here is the bug
    }
}
```

When the function is called with n = 1, I am expecting it to compute 1. / 1 + sumover(0) = 1 / 1 + 0

However, it's computing 1./0 + sumover(0) , why?

Comment: This is also undefined behaviour (the assignment in `--n` is unsequenced relative to the read in `1. / n`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return (1. / n) + sumover(--n);
```

There is no guarantee that the term `(1. / n)` will be calculated before `sumover(--n)`.

The standard doesn't specify that.

Hence the second term may be calculated firstly, then `(1. / n)` becomes `(1. /(n - 1))` and then you get an unexpected output.

Replace it by

```
return (1. / n) + sumover(n - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks. Your reply was helpful !

Comment: I did. It's my first time asking questions in stackoverFlow, thanks for letting me know that I could do this.

Comment: @AdnanMohamed U R welcome